# template designed using p:layout and p:layoutunit does not support responsive. How to make it responsive? Or Do I need to create a template with DIV?

Tags: layout, primefaces, grid

Templates created using p:layout and p:layoutunit does not support responsive. How to make it responsive? Or Do I need to create a different template using Grid CSS as given in primefaces show case?

I am developing a web application with a menu to display on the left, header information like company name, date and other details on top, and the actual content on the center. All pages in the web application will follow the same pattern hence I used a layout and created it using p:layout and p:layoutunit.

But, the pages are looking very small when viewed on mobile (all are getting resized including the menu's on the left). Hence I thought of using responsive grid so that the pages can be viewed in desktops as well as in mobiles.

How I can change the exisitng application developed using the primefaces layout and layoutunits, to become responsive, as layout and layout units are not responsive. The primefaces showcase has given example using DIV only.

Hence, this question. Hope I made my question clear. Thank you.

Comment: why do you need layout? What functionality? Closable? Resizable? Etc... If not use divs. And how/in what way do you expect a layout to be responsive? What should it do? And how did you define your layout? If you give if fixes sizes in px, not it won't resize...

Comment: Let me rephrase my first comment. What functionality of the layout do you use? Closable? Resizable? Etc... If not use divs.